# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi terminal git integrada en visual studio code reconozca las tildes?

Tags: git

He configurado mi editor visual studio code para usar git dentro de el. Todo muy bien pero las tildes de la terminal se muestran de una forma muy caótica, así por ejemplo:

```
'As'$'\303\255'' se ven las tildes en las vocales, separadas por una coma: '$'\303\241'', '$'\303\251'', '$'\303\255'', '$'\303\263'', '$'\303\272'
```

Archivo debería decir: "Así se ven las tildes en las vocales, separadas por una coma: á, é, í, ó, ú"

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con eso, qué debo hacer y por qué ocurre.

Desde ya muchas gracias.